# rotate text block in metro application

Tags: windows-8, rotation, microsoft-metro

I wrote (in windows 8 cr,vs2011) an app and in it I rotated a text block.
Now in windows 8 rc and vs 2012 in the same app the rotation is not working.

```
textblock.ManipulationMode = (lastTB.ManipulationMode & ~ManipulationModes.System) | ManipulationModes.Rotate | ManipulationModes.RotateInertia;
textblock.ManipulationDelta += lastTB_ManipulationDelta;
```

the event is not working .

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the Manipulation events have changed a bit in the Release Preview. This document gives you the details on what has changed in the APIs : [Migrating your Windows 8 Consumer Preview app to Windows 8 Release Preview](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=251943)

Specifically, the events now use degrees instead of radians. So perhaps you may have to change your code to reflect that?

Comment: Thank you, very helpful document.But the problem is that it seems that the event isn't firing.

Comment: Perhaps if you post a full code sample with XAML, we can try to replicate it?

Comment: Here is the c# code.The TextBox is added in the code.There is a tapped event  that "select" the TextBox and then i should be able to rotate it.textBox.Tapped += textBox_Tapped;
            textBox.AddHandler(TappedEvent, new TappedEventHandler(textBox_Tapped), true); AND the text_tapped is: tb.ManipulationMode = (tb.ManipulationMode & ~ManipulationModes.System) | ManipulationModes.Rotate | ManipulationModes.RotateInertia;
            tb.ManipulationDelta += tb;
            tb.AddHandler(ManipulationDeltaEvent, new ManipulationDeltaEventHandler(tb), true);